# NodeJs how to ungzip data received with post on http

Tags: node.js

Hello I have to do an homework and I don't know why not working. I have to handle a POST request, in witch a gz file is sent and I have to decompress it in the path specified by path parameter... I don't know why it doesn't work... maybe I am stupid at using curl command :P

```
function handle_post(req,res,path,cb){

    function warn(err,event){
        if(err)
            console.warn(`Request ${event}, could not close ${path}`)
        else
            console.warn(`Request ${event}, ${path} closed succesfully`)
    }

    if( Fs.existsSync(path) )
        return cb(400,JSON.stringify({error: "file already exist"}));

    var out= Fs.createWriteStream(path);
    res.pipe( Zlib.createGunzip() ).pipe( out );

    out.on('finish',() => cb(200,JSON.stringify({error : null, "written bytes":out.bytesWritten})+'\n'));
    req.on('aborted',() => warn(err,'aborted') );
    req.on('error',(err)=>{
        cb(500,JSON.stringify({error : err.message, "written bytes":ws.bytesWritten})+'\n')
    });
}

var s=Http.createServer(
    (req,res) => {
        console.log("Request: "+req.method+" URL: "+req.url);

        function send(code,json_string){
            res.writeHead(code,{"Content-Type" : "application/json"});
            res.end(json_string)
        }

        if(req.method=='GET')
            handle_get(home+req.url,send);
        else if(req.method=='POST'){
            var parsed_url=Url.parse(req.url,true);
            var path=parsed_url.query.path;
            if(!path)
                return send(400,JSON.stringify({error : 'Missing path'})+'\n');
            handle_post(req,res,home+'/'+path,send);
        }
    });
s.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistypo, the solution is: `req.pipe( Zlib.createGunzip() ).pipe( out );`
it is the request that must be piped